# How to scrollIntoView and scroll inner container without scrolling the whole body

Tags: javascript

I have an outer container which includes inner container both with overflow.
The inner container contains a few elements and I want to scrollIntoView for a specific element. What happens is that te body and inner containers scrolls, I want only the inner container to scroll.
Here is my code:

```css
.outerContainer{
    height: 150vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.innerContainer{
    width: 500px;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: aqua;
    overflow: auto;
}
li{
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li id="target">4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("target").scrollIntoView();
</script>
```

Comment: Your `outerContainer` does not seem like it would scroll – it does not have an `overflow-y` property of `scroll` or `auto`. Do you mean you do not want the `body` to scroll? Otherwise, consider adjusting your example code to demonstrate how the `outerContainer` scrolls.

Comment: @Wongjn "Do you mean you do not want the body to scroll?" - Yes, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You could save the current position of the window scroll, do the `scrollIntoView()` and then scroll back to the saved scroll position afterwards.

```js
const { scrollX, scrollY } = window;
document.getElementById("target").scrollIntoView();
window.scroll(scrollX, scrollY);
```

```css
.outerContainer{
    height: 150vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.innerContainer{
    width: 500px;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: aqua;
    overflow: auto;
}
li{
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li id="target">4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```